# What is the conversion rate of real money to gold?

Tags: hearthstone

I want to spend real money on Hearthstone and want to spend it as efficiently as possible. What are the options to spend money and what is their respective conversion rate to gold?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's the list of all currently available purchasing options and their *gold per US Dollar*, *gold per Euro* and *gold per British Pound* rates, sorted in descending order by efficiency. If the rounded *gold/$* rate matches, *gold/€* is used next. All figures are rounded to full gold. Note that these rates can be interpreted as the amount of gold you save when you buy something with real money (see below for an example). They are not related to the gameplay or card value you end up with.

- **Curse of Naxxramas 5 wings bundle**
  `140 g/$  159 g/€  200 g/£`
- **Curse of Naxxramas 2 wings bundle**
  `140 g/$  156 g/€  200 g/£`
- **Curse of Naxxramas 4 wings bundle**
  `140 g/$  156 g/€  200 g/£`
- **Curse of Naxxramas 3 wings bundle**
  `140 g/$  150 g/€  183 g/£`
- **Curse of Naxxramas single wing**
  `100 g/$  117 g/€  140 g/£`
- **60 packs bundle**
   `86 g/$   95 g/€  125 g/£`
- **40 packs bundle**
   `80 g/$   89 g/€  114 g/£`
- **Arena entry**
   `75 g/$   84 g/€  101 g/£`
- **15 packs bundle**
   `75 g/$   83 g/€  107 g/£`
- **7 packs bundle**
   `70 g/$   78 g/€  100 g/£`
- **2 packs bundle**
   `67 g/$   74 g/€  101 g/£`

A few intereting implications:

- Naxxramas bundles all offer roughly the same ratio in USD, but in EUR and GBP, the 3 wings bundle is significantly less efficient.
- In GBP, the 15 packs bundle is more efficient than Arena entries, in EUR, it's reversed. In USD, Arena is only marginally more efficient because you save 10 cents for 10 Arena entries compared to 1 cent for the bundle due to the *x.99* pricing.
- In GBP, the 2 packs bundle is more efficient than the 7 packs bundle.
- Even without the bundle discount, a Naxxramas wing is still more efficient than packs or Arena entries.
- The ordering of the 2 wings and 4 wings bundle is due to the same effect happening with USD Arena vs. 15-packs.

Here's an example of how the calculation works, using USD:

Let's take the **40 packs bundle**. If you had purchased those packs with gold, it would have cost you 4000 gold, which means the nearly 50 dollars you spent saved you the 4000 gold you would have had to give for the same 40 packs. In other words, each dollar saved you 80 gold.
Compare this to the **Arena entry**. If you had purchased it with gold, it would have cost you 150 gold. The nearly 2 dollars you spent saved you the 150 gold you would have had to give for the same Arena entry. Which means, each of those 2 dollars saved you 75 gold.
In the long run (assuming you spend enough for the single transactions to not matter any more), it's thus more gold efficient to buy 40 packs bundles than it is to buy Arena entries. Of course, that only applies if you're interested in buying both of these in the first place. Many people advise against buying packs in favor of Arena because the possible benefits are greater, but it takes much more time to get from Arena what you'd get from a 40 pack bundle, so it comes down to personal preference and how much time you want to invest into getting new cards.

Comment: So if I understand your table by purchasing 40 packs at $49.99 I am saving myself 80 gold?

Comment: 80 gold per dollar. If you had purchased those packs with gold, it would have cost you 4000 gold, which means the nearly 50 dollars you spent saved you the 4000 gold you would have had to give for the same 40 packs, or each dollar saved you 80 gold.

Comment: Sweet now I fully understand your meaning. It would improve the answer to incorporate this or another explicit example. Thank you for providing this information!

Comment: @ahsteele Good idea, I added the example and expanded it a little.

Comment: Cool I like the addition. Thanks for the great answer!